# How to get message from agent ( in aws connect ) to serverless lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, chatbot, amazon-lex, aws-chatbot

My intention is to build a chatbot thru aws lex and optionally communicate with agent in aws connect.
For this I have created a custom chatbot widget which connects to api gateway and forwards message to lex thru websocket and respond back to chatbot widget. I also redirect these message to agent rather than lex in cases where customer whats to chat with agent.

Im able to send message from lamda to agent, but I am having trouble receiving message back from agent. How can solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find it easier to use Amazon Connect for both the bot and the agent.

- Add an Amazon Lex bot to Connect, this will let you route from the bot to an agent in a contact flow https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/amazon-lex.html
- You can then use Connect's APIs to connect both to your bot and your agent from your widget (there are samples linked from here) https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/enable-chat-in-app.html
- Depending on what else you are doing in your chat widget, you may not even need a custom one, you may be able to use the pre-built one https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/add-chat-to-website.html